# Code Is Only Writing Last Data To Excel Repeatedly

Tags: c#, foreach

Instead of writing each element from my foreach loop, my syntax is only writing the last value of the foreach loop to every cell.  I am sure this is something that I have overlooked, but what needs to be changed in my syntax so that it will write each element of the foreach loop accordingly on each line?

```
foreach (var calcs in dictionary)
{
    var FileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "WriteDataToExcelThroughCode.xlsx"));
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(FileInfo))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets["TTest2"];
        //ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

        ws.Cells["A24:C36"].Clear();

        int z = 0;
        int x = 24;
        while (z <= numofrows)
        {
            ws.Cells["A" + x + ":A" + x].Value = calcs.Key;
            ws.Cells["B" + x + ":B" + x].Value = dictionary[calcs.Key][0];
            ws.Cells["C" + x + ":C" + x].Value = dictionary[calcs.Key][1];
            //ws.Cells["D" + x + "D" + x].Value = dictionary[calcs.Key][2];
            x = x + 1;
            z = z + 1;
        }
        package.Save();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
To better illustrate what my intended results are, is as follows.
Hypothetical calcs contains the following info

```
James 1   2
Jose  3   4
Bob   5   6
```

I want the following info to be written to the following cells
A24 = James    B24 = 1    C24 = 2
A25 = Jose     B25 = 3    C25 = 4
A26 = Bob      B26 = 5    C26 = 6

**Edit 2** 
My variable `numofrows` is set-up like so

```
int start = Convert.ToInt32(txtstart.Text);
int end = Convert.ToInt32(txtEnd.Text) + 1;
int numofrows = end - start;

int[] abc = Enumerable.Range(start, end-start).ToArray();

foreach (int a in abc)
{
    Dictionary<int, int[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();
    dictionary.Add(a, new int[] { 2, 3 });
    foreach (var calcs in dictionary)
    {
      // original code
     }
}



    private void btnHitIT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int start = Convert.ToInt32(Alpha);
    int end = Convert.ToInt32(AlphaEnd)+1;
    int numofrows = end - start;
    int[] angles = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start).ToArray();
    foreach (int a in angles)
    {
        Dictionary<int, int[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();
        dictionary.Add("Jack", new int[] { 2, 3 });
        dictionary.Add("James", new int[] { 7, 11 });
        dictionary.Add("Jason", new int[] { 14, 21 });
        pDrawingArea.Invalidate();
        var FileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "WriteDataToExcelThroughCode.xlsx"));
        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(FileInfo))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets["TTest2"];
            int x = 24;
            foreach (var calcs in dictionary)
            {
                ws.Cells["A24:C36"].Clear();
                for (int z = 0; z <= numofrows; ++z)
                {
                    ws.Cells["A" + x + ":A" + x].Value = calcs.Key;
                    ws.Cells["B" + x + ":B" + x].Value = dictionary[calcs.Key][0];
                    ws.Cells["C" + x + ":C" + x].Value = dictionary[calcs.Key][1];
                    ++x;
                }
            }
            package.Save();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining and incrementing the variable `x` at the wrong place. You need to define it outside the `foreach` loop and increment it outside your `while` loop (but inside the `foreach` loop).

I have changed your inside `while` loop to a more appropriate `for` loop.

Also move the `WorkSheet` definition outside the `foreach` loop, since there is no reason to constantly open and close the excel file.

I notice that you search twice for the value in `Dictionary` given that you already have that value in `calcs.Value`

```
var FileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "WriteDataToExcelThroughCode.xlsx"));
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(FileInfo))
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets["TTest2"];
    //ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
    int x = 24;
    foreach (var calcs in dictionary)
    {
        ws.Cells["A24:C36"].Clear();

        for (int z = 0; z <= numofrows; ++z)
        {
            ws.Cells["A" + x + ":A" + x].Value = calcs.Key;
            ws.Cells["B" + x + ":B" + x].Value = calcs.Value[0];
            ws.Cells["C" + x + ":C" + x].Value = calcs.Value[1];
            //ws.Cells["D" + x + "D" + x].Value = calcs.Value[2];
            ++x;
        }
        package.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: is the ++x; and ++z; the same as me setting z = z + 1?

Comment: @YohanGreenburg Yes. There are multiple ways to write it (`++x`, `x += 1`, `x = x + 1`). and `++x` is the clearest way to increment by `1`

Comment: Utilizing the syntax in your post, only thee last set of values are being wrote to Excel

Comment: yes i did.  Stepping through my code, I think I uncover what my issue is (still syntax).  What I want to do is have the content of calcs write to cells A24, B24, C24 - then have the next values of calcs write to A25, B25, C25.  As the code stands now, the value of calcs is being written to A24, B24, C24.  Does that explain what I am after and what is occuring?

Comment: That will write the last element to each line.  So in my edited post this writes Bob 5 6 to all cells.

Comment: I am performing a calculation for a series of numbers, so I take a start number, and an end number and get all numbers between.  I was trying to use the variable numofrows to know exactly how many times to iterate the loop.  Let me edit OP to show this data.

Comment: @YohanGreenburg As I already said, the code works fine as per what I understand of your needs. Also, the inner `for` loop is just repeating verbatim, potentially causing you some confusion

Comment: I do not understand.  Even when I take the above syntax (my most recent edit) and create a new project, the syntax is still only populating the last set of data for Jason 3 times